# Sample with a max

Tags: r, sampling

If I want to sample numbers  to create a vector I do:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(1:100,200, replace = TRUE)
sum(x)
# [1] 10228
```

What if I want to sample 20 random numbers that sum to 100, and then 30 numbers but still sum to 100. This I imagine will be more of a challenge than it seems. `?sample` and searching Google has not provided me with a clue. And a loop to sample then reject if not close enough( e.g. within 5) of the desired sum I guess may take some time.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

an example would be:

```
foo(10,100) # ten random numbers that sum to 100. (not including zeros)
# 10,10,20,7,8,9,4,10,2,20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another attempt. It doesn't use `sample`, but uses `runif`. I've added an optional "message" to the output showing the sum, which can be triggered using the `showSum` argument. There is also a `Tolerance` argument that specifies how close to the target is required.

```
SampleToSum <- function(Target = 100, VecLen = 10, 
                        InRange = 1:100, Tolerance = 2, 
                        showSum = TRUE) {
  Res <- vector()
  while ( TRUE ) {
    Res <- round(diff(c(0, sort(runif(VecLen - 1)), 1)) * Target)
    if ( all(Res > 0)  & 
         all(Res >= min(InRange)) &
         all(Res <= max(InRange)) &
         abs((sum(Res) - Target)) <= Tolerance ) { break }
  }
  if (isTRUE(showSum)) cat("Total = ", sum(Res), "\n")
  Res
}
```

Here are some examples.

Notice the difference between the default setting and setting `Tolerance = 0`

```
set.seed(1)
SampleToSum()
# Total =  101 
#  [1] 20  6 11 20  6  3 24  1  4  6
SampleToSum(Tolerance=0)
# Total =  100 
#  [1] 19 15  4 10  1 11  7 16  4 13
```

You can verify this behavior by using `replicate`. Here's the result of setting `Tolerance = 0` and running the function 5 times.

```
system.time(output <- replicate(5, SampleToSum(
  Target = 1376,
  VecLen = 13,
  InRange = 10:200,
  Tolerance = 0)))
# Total =  1376 
# Total =  1376 
# Total =  1376 
# Total =  1376 
# Total =  1376 
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.144   0.000   0.145
output
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]   29   46   11   43  171
#  [2,]  103  161  113  195  197
#  [3,]  145  134   91  131  147
#  [4,]  154  173  138   19   17
#  [5,]  197   62  173   11   87
#  [6,]  101  142   87  173   99
#  [7,]  168   61   97   40  121
#  [8,]  140  121   99  135  117
#  [9,]   46   78   31  200   79
# [10,]  140  168  146   17   56
# [11,]   21  146  117  182   85
# [12,]   63   30  180  179   78
# [13,]   69   54   93   51  122
```

And the same for setting `Tolerance = 5` and running the function 5 times.

```
system.time(output <- replicate(5, SampleToSum(
  Target = 1376,
  VecLen = 13,
  InRange = 10:200,
  Tolerance = 5)))
# Total =  1375 
# Total =  1376 
# Total =  1374 
# Total =  1374 
# Total =  1376 
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.060   0.000   0.058 
output
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]   65  190  103   15   47
#  [2,]  160   95   98  196  183
#  [3,]  178  169  134   15   26
#  [4,]   49   53  186   48   41
#  [5,]  104   81  161  171  180
#  [6,]   54  126   67  130  182
#  [7,]   34  131   49  113   76
#  [8,]   17   21  107   62   95
#  [9,]  151  136  132  195  169
# [10,]  194  187   91  163   22
# [11,]   23   69   54   97   30
# [12,]  190   14  134   43  150
# [13,]  156  104   58  126  175
```

Not surprisingly, setting the tolerance to 0 would make the function slower.

---

### Speed (Or lack thereof)

Note that since this is a "random" process, it's hard to guess how long it would take to find the right combination of numbers. For example, using `set.seed(123)`, I ran the following test three times in a row:

```
system.time(SampleToSum(Target = 1163,
                        VecLen = 15,
                        InRange = 50:150))
```

The first run took just over 9 seconds. The second took just over 7.5 seconds. The third took... just under 381 seconds! That's a lot of variation!

Out of curiosity, I added a counter into the function, and the first run took **55026** attempts to arrive at a vector that satisfied all of our conditions! (I didn't bother trying for the second and third attempts.)

It might be good to add some error or sanity checking into the function to make sure the inputs are reasonable. For example, one should not be able to enter `SampleToSum(Target = 100, VecLen = 10, InRange = 15:50)` since with a range of 15 to 50, there's no way to get to 100 AND have 10 values in your vector.

Answer (score 4):

**An attempt using R**

```
# Config
n <- 20L
target <- 100L
vec <- seq(100)
set.seed(123)

# R repeat loop
sumto_repeat <- function(vec,n,target) {
  res <- integer()
  repeat {
    cat("begin:",sum(res),length(res),"\n")
    res <- c( res, sample(vec,1) )
    if( sum(res)<target & length(res)==(n-1) ) {
      res[length(res)+1] <- target - sum(res)
    }
    # cat("mid:",sum(res),length(res),"\n")
    if(sum(res)>target) res <- res[-length(res)]
    if( length(res)>n | length(res)<n & sum(res)==target ) {
      res <- res[-sample(seq(length(res)),1)]
    }
    # cat("end:",sum(res),length(res),"\n")
    # cat(dput(res),"\n")
    if( sum(res)==target & length(res)==n ) break
  }
  res
}

test <- sumto_repeat(vec=vec,n=n,target=target)
> sum(test)
[1] 100
> length(test)
[1] 20
```

Also, I'd give some thought to what distribution you'd like to be drawing from.  I *think* that there are a few different ways of getting it to sum to exactly `target` with `n` elements (for instance, you could make the last element always be `target - sum(res)`) that may or may not have different distributional implications.

**A very similar algorithm in Rcpp, for speeeeed!**

```
cpp_src <- '
Rcpp::IntegerVector xa = clone(x); // Vector to be sampled
Rcpp::IntegerVector na(n); // Number of elements in solution
Rcpp::IntegerVector sa(s); // Sum of solution

int nsampled;
int currentSum;
int dropRandomIndex;
int numZeroes;
Rcpp::IntegerVector remainingQuantity(1);
int maxAttempts = 100;

// Create container for our results
Rcpp::IntegerVector res(maxAttempts);
std::fill( res.begin(), res.end(), NA_INTEGER );

// Calculate min/max so that we can draw random integers from within range
Rcpp::IntegerVector::iterator mn = std::min_element(xa.begin(), xa.end()) ;
Rcpp::IntegerVector::iterator mx = std::max_element(xa.begin(), xa.end()) ;
std::cout << "mx = " << *mx << std::endl;

// Now draw repeatedly
nsampled = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < maxAttempts; i++ ) {
  std::cout << "\\n" << i;
  int r = *mn + (rand() % (int)(*mx - *mn + 1));
  res[i] = xa[r+1];
  // Calculate n and s for current loop iteration
  numZeroes = 0;
  for( int j = 0; j < maxAttempts; j++) 
    if(res[j]==0) numZeroes++;
  std::cout << " nz= " << numZeroes ;
  nsampled = maxAttempts - sum( is_na(res) ) - numZeroes - 1;
  currentSum = std::accumulate(res.begin(),res.begin()+i,0); // Cant just use Rcpp sugar sum() here because it freaks at the NAs
  std::cout << " nsamp= " << nsampled << " sum= " << currentSum;
  if(nsampled == na[0]-1) {  
    std::cout << " One element away. ";
    remainingQuantity[0] = sa[0] - currentSum;
    std::cout << "remainingQuantity = " << remainingQuantity[0];
    if( (remainingQuantity[0] > 0) && (remainingQuantity[0]) < *mx ) {
      std::cout << "Within range.  Prepare the secret (cheating) weapon!\\n";
      std::cout << sa[0] << " ";
      std::cout << currentSum << " ";
      std::cout << remainingQuantity[0] << std::endl;
      if( i != maxAttempts ) {
        std::cout << "Safe to add one last element on the end.  Doing so.\\n";
        res[i] = remainingQuantity[0];
      }
      currentSum = sa[0];
      nsampled++;
      if(nsampled == na[0] && currentSum == sa[0]) std::cout << "It should end after this...nsamp= " << nsampled << " and currentSum= " << currentSum << std::endl;
      break;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Out of striking distance.  Dropping random element\\n";
      dropRandomIndex = 0 + (rand() % (int)(i - 0 + 1));
      res[dropRandomIndex] = 0;
    }
  }
  if(nsampled == na[0] && currentSum == sa[0]) {
      std::cout << "Success!\\n";
      for(int l = 0; l <= i+1; l++) 
        std::cout << res[l] << " " ;
      break;
  }
  if(nsampled == na[0] && currentSum != sa[0]) {
    std::cout << "Reached number of elements but sum is ";
    if(currentSum > sa[0]) {
      std::cout << "Too high. Blitz everything and start over!\\n";
      for(int k = 0; k < res.size(); k++) {
        res[k] = NA_INTEGER;
      }
    } else {
      std::cout << "Too low.  \\n";

    }
  }
  if( nsampled < na[0] && currentSum >= sa[0] ) {
    std::cout << "Too few elements but at or above the sum cutoff.  Dropping a random element and trying again.\\n";
    dropRandomIndex = 0 + (rand() % (int)(i - 0 + 1));
    res[dropRandomIndex] = 0;
  }
}
return res;
'

sumto <- cxxfunction( signature(x="integer", n="integer", s="integer"), body=cpp_src, plugin="Rcpp", verbose=TRUE )

testresult <- sumto(x=x, n=20L, s=1000L)
testresult <- testresult[!is.na(testresult)]
testresult <- testresult[testresult!=0]
testresult
cumsum(testresult)
length(testresult)
```

Tried it with a few different values, and produces valid answers unless it runs away.  There's a caveat here, which is that it cheats if it's one away from the desired number of elements and within "striking distance" -- e.g. rather than just drawing the last value it calculates it if that number is valid.

**Benchmarks**

See [gist](https://gist.github.com/gsk3/4740012) for comparison code.

[image: benchmarks]

Comment: The OP wants to specify the number of samples.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Oops!  Changed.

Comment: great answer thanks, it has a heart attack on a few number combinations so i'll play with this, and I'll add an `if n=1 target` but thank you very much

Comment: The example gave sum(test) = 98 here

Comment: @Rcoster Odd.  With what seed?

Comment: The same used in the example (123)

Comment: @Rcoster Thanks.  I'm trying to figure out where the bug is.  It was working before (although maybe by chance?), and it's not triggering the terminal condition for the loop.  More soon.

Comment: @Rcoster Tried to figure out the bug and failed (some quirk of `while` loops maybe?).  Rewrote as a `repeat` instead.  Tested using the above plus `n=30L;target=74L;set.seed(512)`.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, but with floating point numbers, so not exactly what you are looking for, sorry :

```
randomsum <- function(nb, sum) {
  tmp <- sort(runif(nb-1))
  tmp <- c(min(tmp), diff(tmp), 1-max(tmp))
  as.vector(quantile(0:sum, probs=tmp))
}
```

Which would give for example :

```
R> result <- randomsum(10, 1000)
R> result
 [1]  35.282191  66.537308  17.263761 182.837409 120.064363 210.752735
 [7] 143.201079   6.164731  34.936359 182.960064
R> sum(result)
[1] 1000
```

You could use `round` on the result to get integers, but then of course the sum could be slightly different from what you want to get. A quick and dirty workaround can be to alter one of the random values to make your vector sum to the number you want :

```
randomsumint <- function(nb, sum) {
  tmp <- sort(runif(nb-1))
  tmp <- c(min(tmp), diff(tmp), 1-max(tmp))
  res <- as.vector(quantile(0:sum, probs=tmp))
  res <- round(res)
  res[length(res)] <- res[length(res)]+(sum-sum(res))
  res
}
```

Which would give :

```
R> result <- randomsumint(10,1000)
R> result
 [1]  42 152   0  11  74 138   9 138 172 264
R> sum(result)
[1] 1000
```

Not that this is far from perfect, as in some rare cases you could get a negative value in your result.

Comment: +1 very nice although, just a note though 10 will give 11 numbers

Comment: You're right, I just edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want integers (if not then look at the Dirichlet distribution) then this can be thought of as a ball and urn problem (without further restrictions on relationship between the numbers).

If you want 20 numbers then that can be represented by 20 urns.  You want the numbers to sum to 100 so that is 100 balls.  Since you want exactly 20 numbers (skip this step if you want up to 20 numbers, but could be fewer) you start by placing 1 ball in each urn, then randomly distribute the remaining balls between the urns.  Count the number of balls in each urn and you will have 20 numbers that sum to 100.

As R code:

```
as.vector(table( c( 1:20, sample(1:20, 80, replace=TRUE) ) ))
```

The `as.vector` just strips off the table class and labels.

Quick, simple, exact, no loops, recursion, etc.

For other totals or number of values just change the appropriate pieces above.

Answer (score 2):

I thought of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) and partitions in combinatorics:

```
foo <- function(n,total) {
  while(!exists("x",inherits=FALSE) || 1 %in% diff(x)) {
    x <- sort(c(0,sample.int(n+total,n-1,replace=FALSE),n+total))
  }
  print(x)
  sort(diff(x)-1)
}
```

Another method is to use the [partitions package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partitions/partitions.pdf). This is more suited to enumerating all partitions, but it is okay for now. It works as long as your total number is small.

```
require(partitions)
foo <- function(n,total) { 
  x <- restrictedparts(total,n,include.zero=FALSE)
  return(x[,sample.int(ncol(x),1)])
}
```