# Sampling in r without consecutive identical digits

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R, but I've done a lot of searching and haven't found an answer to my question.

I have a vector with many repetitions of 8 digits:

```
allNum <- c(rep(1, 70), rep(2, 70), rep(3, 35), rep(4, 35), 
            rep(5, 70), rep(6, 70), rep(7, 35), rep(8, 35))
```

Now I want to take a permutation of this (presumably using `sample(allNum, 420, replace=FALSE)`), but I do not want any consecutive identical digits -- for example: 1 2 2 8

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684539/sample-with-a-max/14696912

Comment: Use `any(diff(x) == 0)` to check if there is any consecutive identical digits ? Then keep sampling until you find one?

Comment: What a nicely reproducible first question!

Comment: Graph Theory connection: Imagine a graph where each vertex corresponds to one of your numbers, and where vertices are connected with an edge unless they represent the same number. Your problem is to find a path that visits all the vertices of your graph once, a.k.a. a *Hamiltonian path*. There are probably many algorithms available online.

Answer (score 3):

You have an issue where there is the possibility of choosing elements randomly versus being constrained on your choices. In particular, if the number of elements you have to choose from is more than $2n-1$ where $n$ is the number of times the most frequent element occurs, you can choose a random element (consistent with the previous constraints). However, if those numbers are equal, then the most frequent value must be in every-other position for the rest of the sequence (and the values between can be randomly assigned). Recognizing this constraint allows a single pass through (no more random selections than there are elements in the original vector).

```
permute.nonconsec <- function(allNum) {
  fully.constrained <- function(x) {
    2*max(table(x)) - 1 == length(x)
  }
  permuted <- numeric(length(allNum))
  permuted[1] <- sample(allNum, 1)
  allNum <- allNum[-min(which(allNum==permuted[1]))]
  for (i in seq_along(allNum)+1) {
    if(fully.constrained(allNum)) {
      # switch to deterministic algorithm
      # determine which value is the constraining one
      r <- rle(sort(allNum))
      limiter <- r$values[r$lengths==max(r$lengths)]
      permuted[seq(i, length(permuted), by=2)] <- limiter
      remaining <- allNum[allNum != limiter]
      if (length(remaining)>0) {
        permuted[seq(i+1, length(permuted), by=2)] <- 
          remaining[sample.int(length(remaining))]
      }
      break;
    }
    available <- allNum[allNum != permuted[i-1]]
    permuted[i] <- available[sample.int(length(available), 1)]
    allNum <- allNum[-min(which(allNum==permuted[i]))]
  }
  permuted
}
```

This will fail if there is no possible arrangement: `length(x) < 2 * max(table(x)) - 1`, but an initial check for that could be added if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14696912/697568), one method is to brute-force and keep sampling until you get a permutation with the desired characteristics.

```
nonconsec.permute <- function(pop,size) {
  while(!exists("x",inherits=FALSE) || 0 %in% diff(x)) {
    x <- sample(pop, size, replace=F)
  }
}
```

However, the following command takes a long time because identical consecutive digits are extremely common in the example you present. So this approach would not be feasible in your specific situation.

```
nonconsec.permute(allNum,420)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple algorithm for that:

```
N = 420
i = as.integer(runif(1, 1, length(allNum)))
result = allNum[i]
allNum = allNum[-i]
while (N != 1) {
  N = N - 1

  # pick a random value that's different from last chosen one
  last = result[length(result)]
  i = as.integer(runif(1, 1, sum(allNum != last)))
  result = c(result, allNum[allNum != last][i])

  # remove any (doesn't matter which) element of allNum that's
  # equal to last choice, to sample without replacement
  last = result[length(result)]
  allNum = allNum[-which(allNum == last)[1]]
}
```

Comment: The problem with this algorithm is that you can end up with `allNum` containing all the same value (say, `allNum=c(2,2)`) in which case it picks a 2, but then the next pass through, `sum(allNum != last)` is 0 and there are no available/valid values to sample.

Comment: That's not a problem. Running the algorithm with that input and `N=2` you'll get `result=c(2,NA)`. So you can easily check whether the sampling you tried to do was achievable (and you'll also get the max achievable part).