# How do i split a number randomly into multiple numbers given the number and n groups?

Tags: r, split, probability, addition

For instance , if the number is 100 and the number of groups is 4 it should give any random list of 4 numbers that add upto 100:

input number = 100

number of groups = 4

Possible outputs:

25, 25, 25, 25

10, 20, 30, 40

15, 35,  2, 48

The output should only be one list generated. More application oriented example would be **how i would split a probability 1 into multiple groups given the number of groups** using R?

Comment: I think this question might be a duplicate. Does my answer [here, where I presented a function called `SampleToSum`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14687223/1270695) help?

Comment: It does achieve the same thing, but it doesn't exactly produce to the sum always and tolerance to zero does take a lot of time. Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rmultinom` might be handy here:

```
x <- rmultinom(n = 1, size = 100, prob = rep(1/4, 4))
x
colSums(x)
```

Here I draw one vector, with a total size of 100, which is splitted into 4 groups.

Comment: Thanks !! This really simplified the process !

Answer (score 4):

You can try following

```
total <- 100
n <- 4
as.vector(table(sample(1:n, size = total, replace = T)))
## [1] 23 27 24 26

as.vector(table(sample(1:n, size = total, replace = T)))
## [1] 25 26 28 21

as.vector(table(sample(1:n, size = total, replace = T)))
## [1] 24 20 28 28
```

Comment: I really like your method. I was thinking more in terms of generating random numbers ceiling(runif and rnorm) for first few groups and subtract to get last group . This usually ended in some negative values being added. This one eliminates that problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to probabilities, I think this is a good idea:

```
generate.probabilities <- function(n){
    bordersR <- c(sort(runif(n-1)), 1)
    bordersL <- c(0, bordersR[1:(n-1)])
    bordersR - bordersL
}
```

It gives you n numbers from random distribution which sum up to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Define the parameters for generality

```
inN <- 100 # input number
nG <- 4 # number of groups
```

Following storaged's idea that we only need 3 random numbers to split the space into 4 regions, but requiring integers, the inner borders can be found as:

```
sort(sample(inN,nG-1, replace = TRUE))
```

The OP wanted the count in each group which we can find by

```
diff(c(0,sort(sample(inN,nG-1, replace = TRUE)), inN))
```